# I don't have a dedicated GPU and I can't install DirectX to play NFS Most Wanted

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

I want to play NFS Most Wanted on the PC and I do not have any Graphic Card. While installing this system asks to install Directx (Even I have already installed it) and displays an Internal system error.

Please somebody guide me about this game and Directx Issues.

Comment: So you're saying you want to use your motherboard's onboard video?  Chances are, it's not going to be very capable of playing games like that at all as that's a fairly graphics heavy game.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your system config

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Do you have an Intel integrated graphic chip perhaps? Which one? What is the exact error? (Screenshot please.) When does it come up? Provide further details and I'll reopen.

Comment: Thank you so much brother. Here are some details about my PC:

Comment: And, for now I am not able to add images/screenshot. Admin are not allowing me......  :-(

Comment: This error message displays when I run DirectX while installing NFS game, "An internal system error occurred. Please refer to DXError.log and DirectX.log in your windows folder to determine problem"

Answer (score 2):

Every computer built in the last 5 years or so has a 3D capable graphics card.  Need for Speed Most Wanted has [modest system requirements](http://gamesystemrequirements.com/games.php?id=297), so it's likely that if you have a fairly recent computer, you'll be able to play it.

You can identify the model and type of your graphics card by going into the [device manager](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/f/open-device-manager-windows-7.htm).  You may also need to update your graphics drivers before you'll be able to play.

As far as your DirectX error goes, I found [one guide](http://www.tweakguides.com/NFSMW_3.html) that gave a hint:

> DirectX Error when Installing: When installing the game if you get an error that DirectX9.0c is not installed, even if you've installed DX9.0c already, then find the game's Autorun.exe file (in the base directory of the game CD), right-click on it, select Properties, go to the Compatibility tab, tick the 'Run this program in compatibility mode for' and select 'Windows 2000'. Then double-click on Autorun.exe to begin installation. Make sure to turn off compatibility mode after installing the game.

If this doesn't fix your problem, you're going to have to provide more detail in your question.

Comment: Hello brother, The Autorun.exe does not have the Compatibility mode tab/option.. Please somebody help me to solve the problem