# Directx.log internal system error when trying to install Need for Speed: Most Wanted

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005, directx-9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I don't have a dedicated GPU and I can't install DirectX to play NFS Most Wanted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38759/i-dont-have-a-dedicated-gpu-and-i-cant-install-directx-to-play-nfs-most-wanted)

Still nobody is solved the problem about  Directx.log. Following message occurs when I install directx.

"An internal system error occored.
Please refer to DXError.log and DirectX.log in your windows folder to determine the problem."

I hope that somebody would understand this error. Below I have described My PC configurations so you can better understand the internal error.

Operating system: Windows 7 32bit
Asus mother board: P5GC-MX/1333
Intel Chipset: i945G
Ram: DDR2 3GB
Processor: Intel Pentium E2180

are above details sufficient? I have seen that my other friends are using NFS Most wanted without graphic and same PC configuration.

Please help me to solve the problem. I have tried so many things to fix this problem. I am waiting if anybody give me 100% working tips.

Thanks,

Comment: Is this a repost of your [earlier question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38759/i-dont-have-a-dedicated-gpu-and-i-cant-install-directx-to-play-nfs-most-wanted)?  If so, you should edit it with these details instead of opening a new question.  Also, if nobody was able to answer it, it might be that we don't know.  Have you tried contacting EA customer support?

Comment: Good Answer mate. 1000% yes for you